# Autofac WebForms in Onion Architecture

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, autofac, onion-architecture

I am following onion architecture whose Bootstrapper part is build with `Autofac`.

Architecture is as follows:

1. Core
2. DependencyInjection (Autofac is here)
3. Service
4. Presentation (MVC 5)
5. Test

I needed some WebForm.aspx pages to show my reports. so I am following the instructions given the the link for integration of WebForms with Autofac: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html

Here is the code from DependencyInjection:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(IocConfig), "RegisterDependencies")]
namespace DependencyInjection.App_Start
{
    public class IocConfig : IContainerProviderAccessor
    {
         // Provider that holds the application container.
        static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

        // Instance property that will be used by Autofac HttpModules
        // to resolve and inject dependencies.
        public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
        {
            get { return _containerProvider; }
        }

        public static void RegisterDependencies()
        {
            // Build up your application container and register your dependencies.
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register your MVC controllers. (MvcApplication is the name of
            // the class in Global.asax.)
            builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);

            // OPTIONAL: Register model binders that require DI.
            builder.RegisterModelBinders(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
            builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

            // OPTIONAL: Register web abstractions like HttpContextBase.
            builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

            // OPTIONAL: Enable property injection in view pages.
            builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());



            // OPTIONAL: Enable property injection into action filters.
            builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

 builder.RegisterType<MyService().As<IMyService().InstancePerRequest();

            // Once you're done registering things, set the container
           // provider up with your registrations.
           _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(container);
        }
    }
}
```

In App.Config of DependencyInjection, I have added:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>      
      <add name="ContainerDisposal" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule, Autofac.Integration.Web"/>
      <add name="PropertyInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ContainerDisposal" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
      <add name="PropertyInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>    
  </system.webServer>
```

Still it is not working. MyService is still `null`. When I add the App.Config setting into Web.Config of my Presentation, I got the following error:

> This module requires that the HttpApplication (Global Application
>   Class) implements IContainerProviderAccessor

Answer (score 0):

Autofac ASP.net WebForm integration requires that the `HttpApplication` implements `IContainerProviderAccessor`.

If you want to use `WebActivator` with your `IocConfig` class. The Global.asax class still have to implement the `IContainerProviderAccessor` interface to let the HttpModule find the Autofac container.

You can implement this interface by relying on the `IocConfig` implementation

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class Global : HttpApplication, IContainerProviderAccessor
{
  // Instance property that will be used by Autofac HttpModules
  // to resolve and inject dependencies.
  public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
  {
    get { return IocConfig.ContainerProvider; }
  }
}
```

and your `IocConfig` doesn't need to implement `IContainerProviderAccessor` but need to have a public static property for the `IContainerProvider`

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(IocConfig), 
                                                   "RegisterDependencies")]

namespace DependencyInjection.App_Start
{
    public class IocConfig : IContainerProviderAccessor
    {
         // Provider that holds the application container.
        static IContainerProvider _containerProvider;

        // Instance property that will be used by Autofac HttpModules
        // to resolve and inject dependencies.
        public static IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
        {
            get { return _containerProvider; }
        }
```

Comment: But then it will violate the Onion Architecture design.

Comment: This solution requires Autofac to be present in Presentation layer which will violate the Onion Architecture design. All dependency Injection related libraries should be at DependencyInjection Layer.